# Make error on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, themes

When im running make for building oxygen-transparent theme , I receive the following error :

```
kde@wilsonzaizai-Satellite-L510:~/oxygen-transparent/build$ sudo make install
[ 0%] Built target oxygentransparentstyle_automoc
[ 5%] Built target oxygentransparentstyle
[ 5%] Built target kwin3_oxygen_transparent_automoc
[ 18%] Built target kwin3_oxygen_transparent
[ 18%] Built target kwin_oxygen_transparent_config_automoc
Linking CXX shared module ../../lib/kwin_oxygen_transparent_config.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -loxygenstyle 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/kwin_oxygen_transparent_config.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [decoration/config/CMakeFiles/kwin_oxygen_transparent_config.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is -loxygenstyle ?

Answer (score 3):

-loxygenstyle means that it must be linked to the "oxygenstyle" library,  which is not currently installed on your system.

If you search for liboxygenstyle on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=liboxygenstyle&mode=filename&suite=maverick&arch=any), you will find that it is provided by the package with the name "kdebase-workspace-dev", install it and retry.